# How to unregister wrong Cython extension?

Tags: cython

I created Cython Extension

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import numpy
print (numpy.__file__)
setup(name='spacy text app',
  ext_modules=cythonize("spacy.pyx", language="c++"),
  include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
 )
```

and register it as same name as "spacy" package name.

```
python spacyc.py build_ext --inplace
```

Now when i use spacy

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(u"The firm earned $1.5 million in 2017.")
```

I get this error

```
  File "spacy.pyx", line 1, in init spacy
    from cymem.cymem cimport Pool

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.strings'; 'spacy' is not a package
```

How to unregister wrong Cython extension?

Answer (score 0):

Actually after a few hours I found out that you need to manually delete the .pyd file in the same directory that contains the script. I hope to help someone in the future.